# How to close an iOS app on a real device using appium

Tags: ios, selenium, automated-tests, appium

I'm using appium to automate some tests but I want the application under test to return to the same start in between tests. I think that the easiest way to do this would be to close and reopen the app. Is this possible with appium? If so, how?

(Note: driver.close() does not work)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with driver.quit(). You will need to reconnect but as long as the server is launched with the `--no-reset` switch it should boot up in the state where you left it.

You could also background the app as an alternative using executeScript with "mobile: background" (see https://github.com/mutualmobile/appium/commit/53f0c58857eec512f48732d40ace71b7db4ae32f) or calling the UIAutomation command directly with executeScript. (e.g. `au.background(5)`) for 5 seconds in the background.

Comment: Dan, is there any flag for ios7 real device not to restart app between tests (cucumber features, p.e.). Because after doing it, appium cannot interact again with app stating "Executable "app_name" is already running as process XXX which was launched from the 'launchd' process"